# How do I create individual fields on a node?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I would like to use individual Taxonomy fields on a node - not a preconfigured Content Type. e.g.

- Color: Red
- Year: 2015
- Project details: Short description.

This is just working fine with the Core Field Module. The downside of it is that it's preconfigured on the Content Type. Users can’t add more fields to a node. I need more flexibility. E.g: Thus, I am using a text field with unlimited Number of values.

**Example with Core Text Fields**
[image: Example with Core Text Fields]

However I am missing Taxonomy’s term reference feature: People have to type in all data on every node. I hope this makes sense. I’ve created a quick mockup to show what I am looking for. **I would love to define individual description and Taxonomy terms.**
[image: What-I-am-looking-for]

What’s the best way to get full flexibility?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ? What you mean by full flexibility ?

Comment: I have updated my questions.

Comment: Looks to me that you can accomplish this with regular fields and you can set the field to Unlimited so you can add more if you need.

Comment: As far as I can see it's not possible with Core fields. Please take a look at my initial question. I have added a quick graphic mockup.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Field Collection and Field Collection Views modules would help you a lot. It allows you to have unlimited fields inside a node and in your case, I guess you'd have the taxonomy and a field for the answer.

This video does an infinitely better job of explaining it than I ever could.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GlfYhsk3X0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It’s not quite what I am looking for. As shown in the video all fields are predefined. In this case I am unable to define individual description and text. Please take a look at my initial question. I have added a quick graphic mockup.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to add new data to a predefined list?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/how-to-add-new-data-to-a-predefined-list/183276#183276)", which describes what you can do with the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module.

In your case, you could use that module also to define 2 fields, which I'd label something like so (or anything else you'd prefer):

- **Attribute** (with values like Material, Color, Year, ...).
- **Value** (with values like Plastic, Red, 2015, ...).

Obviously, if "I" would then want to add like "Taste = Sweet", I'd just have to add "Taste" to the 1st field, and "Sweet" to the 2nd field.

*Sweet* enough?

Comment: Sorry for my the delay in responding. This is almost I was looking for.

How do I change the label name? When I select „Other“ The display looks like this customvalue: red, customvalue: blue


Also how can I use taxonomy with Select (or other) module?